# How to remove video fisheye effect with low overhead

Tags: video-editor, video-streaming, video-recording

I am a "newbie" and currently using an RTSP stream on a PI4 with a POE security camera that has a wide-angle lens on it.

It is my understanding that this effect can be removed via a MATLAB calibration routine.  But, I'm not sure that would require a lot of overhead or not.

Does anyone know of a "low overhead" way to remove this effect for an RTSP stream?